# Iframe in Flexdashboard

Tags: r, iframe, shiny, flexdashboard

Does anyone know how to create an iframe in flexdashboard?

The goal is to pass a link, that opens a web browser (or page or video) in the dashboard itself.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can put an iframe HTML tag inside the R Markdown part of your flexdashboard.

````
Link Page
=======================================================================

<iframe
    src="http://www.gnu.org/" 
    frameborder="0"
    style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" 
    height="100%" 
    width="100%">
</iframe>

```{r}
print("gnu.org")
```
````